# Unity 2d text not rendered properly in scene mode

Tags: unity, text

I am a beginner in Unity and trying to add a text box to my scene. I have done this before and was able to do it properly.

**Problem**

But recently I created a new project, added a text element to it, but text is not rendered properly in that text box. Anything I type in it is shown as boxes.

Here is the screenshot for it.

[image: Screenshot updated]

While text is shown properly in play mode. I also tried adding custom fonts in it but it didn't made any effect.

What can be the cause for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to 'shaded' inside this dropdown. It's right next to the scene view tab.

[image]